# Issue with custom list adapter and ViewHolder pattern after swaping items in list

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

Item is a custom class that has, among other things, a string for a title and an enum for saving the state of a checkbox.

```
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Say I have 3 items in my arraylist and I want to swap the position of items 2 and 3.

```
// Move item down
public void moveDown(int position){
    if ( position < mItems.size() -1 ) {
        Collections.swap(mItems, position, position + 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I can see, while debugging *mItems*, that items are correctly swapped.

Next thing, the getView function will be called for each arraylist item.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Item item = mItems.get(position);

    View myView = convertView;
    if ( null == myView )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder  viewHolder  = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.title        = (TextView)       myView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        viewHolder.statusView   = (CheckBox)       myView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);

        myView.setTag(viewHolder);
        myView.setLongClickable(true);
    }

    final ViewHolder myHolder = (ViewHolder) myView.getTag() ;

    // Display Title in TextView
    myHolder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

    // Set up Status CheckBox
    if ( item.getStatus() == Status.NOTDONE )
    {
        myHolder.statusView.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        myHolder.statusView.setChecked(true);
    }

    //  Must also set up an OnCheckedChangeListener, which is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
    myHolder.statusView
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    if ( isChecked == true ) {
                        item.setStatus(Status.DONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.setStatus(Status.NOTDONE);
                    }
                }
            });

    return myView;

}
```

Now, say that at the beggining, these were the items

Item: 1 | Title A | Checkbox status: Not checked
Item: 2 | Title B | Checkbox status: Not checked
Item: 3 | Title C | Checkbox status: Checked

and after the swap, we got this:

Item: 1 | Title A | Checkbox status: Not checked
Item: 2 | Title C | Checkbox status: Checked
Item: 3 | Title B | Checkbox status: Not checked

The **second time** getView gets called, as the checkbox status is checked, this will be called:

```
myHolder.statusView.setChecked(true);
```

But the odd part is: after that, I see a call to the

```
 myHolder.statusView
   .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
       {
           if ( isChecked == true ) {
               item.setStatus(Status.DONE);
           }
           else
           {
               item.setStatus(Status.NOTDONE);
           }
       }
   });
```

but the *item* is pointed to the **third item**( title 'B') and the related checkbox, so I end up incorrectly setting the status of **item 3** to Done

What should I do to prevent the onCheckedChanged listener to get called for item 3, after I set it to checked for item 3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it happen without using view holder?

Comment: @pskink no, it only happens when I use the ViewHolder. If i take away the if ( null == myView ), then the behaviour looks OK

Comment: no, you cannot remove " if ( null == myView )", its for view reusing purposes, just remove view holder pattern, its a myth that it improves the performance, but almost always introduces problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating the affected views after swapping two items. A class variable would tell the getView() function when the views should be recreated

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating the viewholder in class and not in getview ()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you rephrase it?